# I can't upload a live video on instagram with api mgp25 in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, instagram, instagramapi-mgp25

I have problem with upload a video file on live Instagram with 
using mgp25 API.

```php
        $insta_obj->login($this->username[$i], $this->password[$i]);
        $ffmpegPath = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'; $ffmpeg = 
        \InstagramAPI\Media\Video\FFmpeg::factory($ffmpegPath);
        $stream = $insta_obj->live->create(); 
        $broadcastId = $stream->getBroadcastId(); 
        $insta_obj->live->start($broadcastId); 
        $streamUploadUrl = $stream->getUploadUrl(); 
        $streamUploadUrl = 
    preg_replace('#^rtmps://([^/]+?):443/#ui','rtmp://\1:80/',$stream>getUploadUr
    l()); 
        $broadcastProcess = $ffmpeg->runAsync(sprintf('-rtbufsize 256M -re -i %s - 
    acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 
    720x1280 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 
    -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv %s', 
    \Winbox\Args::escape('../view/upload/' . Upload::getEmail() . '/' 
    .$data['name']), \Winbox\Args::escape($streamUploadUrl)));
```

Comment: Please update you question with the result to see what went wrong.

Comment: doesn't upload anything

Comment: and doesn't show error or warning

Comment: @jános_sicz_mesziár

Comment: FFmpeg will always print something to stderr. Capture and display that log.